# Entity Framework Core custom entity resolver

Tags: f#, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for configuring ef core with custom entity creation function. My case is f# domain model with union types, that ef core cannot construct on itself and I don't want to specify CliMutable attribute. I'm looking for thing like https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#type-switching-per-row but with ef core's change tracking to save whole entity later with only changed values.
I've searched through ef core's docs and not found any - maybe sb here can help?

Comment: Maybe this article can help https://codeburst.io/creating-a-f-data-layer-using-entity-framework-core-746ec17d49e5?gi=995a8f6740a2

Comment: No, it isn't about what I've described

Comment: I've been looking into this, but I don't see any way to map an F# discriminated union in EF Core. The problem is that the DU is essentially an abstract base class, and each of its cases is a derived class. However, I don't see any way to access a case's concrete CLR type within F# in order to model it with EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to use value conversions for one object to one column mapping (there are plans to be able to specify multiple columns for one object - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13947). For union types serializing object to json with support of https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson is the only way to go, but schema evolving mechanism needs to be take into consideration upfront. For example in postresql and marten it can be done with javascript transformations (https://martendb.io/documentation/documents/advanced/javascript_transformations/), but in sqlserver 2019 there isn't such an easy mechanism. That's why untill ef core has support for object to multi-column mapping I think dapper with manual row mapping is the best option.

As a side note I can tell that configuring ef core in f# is way harder than in c#, as examples:

- lambda expression trees have to be constructed explicitly:

```
module Lambda =
    let toExpression (``f# lambda`` : Quotations.Expr<'a>) =
        ``f# lambda``
        |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression 
        |> unbox<Expression<'a>>

let expr f = f |> Lambda.toExpression

type MeetingId = MeetingId of Guid

type Meeting = {
    MeetingId: MeetingId
    Title: string
}

type MeetingEntityTypeConfiguration() =
    interface IEntityTypeConfiguration<Meeting> with
        member _.Configure builder =
            builder
                .HasKey(expr <@ Func<_,_>(fun x -> x.MeetingId :> obj) @>) |> ignore            
            builder
                .Property(expr <@ Func<_,_>(fun p -> p.Title) @>)
                .HasColumnName("Title") |> ignore
            builder
                .Property(expr <@ Func<_,_>(fun p -> p.MeetingId) @>)
                .HasColumnName("Id")
                .HasConversion(
                    expr <@ Func<_,_>(fun p ->
                        let (MeetingId v) = p
                        v) @>,
                    expr <@ Func<_,_>(fun v -> MeetingId(v)) @>
                    ) |> ignore
```

- dbContext's dbSets have to be properties with backing fields instead of autogenerated properties:

```
type public MeetingsContext() =
    inherit DbContext()
    
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable meetingsDbSet: DbSet<Meeting>
    
    member public this.Meetings
        with get () = this.meetingsDbSet
        and set (v) = this.meetingsDbSet <- v
```